# Is My Approach to the Todo App Delete Function Wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and just created a simple todo app using only React. My todo app has the standard structure of having a text input and an "ADD" button next to it. The user would type their todo in the input and every time they click on the "ADD" button next to it, a new ordered list of their inputs would appear underneath the input and "ADD" button.

[image]

The user can also delete a todo entry by clicking on the entries individually, like this:

[image]

To accomplish this behaviour of deleting entries, I used this delete function:

```
delete(elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.listArray.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.listArray[i] === elem) {
        this.state.listArray.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({
          listArray: this.state.listArray
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

My todo app works exactly the way that I want it to work, but as I look at other people's more conventional approach to this delete function, they either just simply use the splice method or the filter method.

For the splice method approach, they apparently just simply "remove" the unwanted entry from the **listArray** when the user clicks the particular entry. This does not work for me as using this method results in all my entries getting deleted except for the entry that I clicked on, which is the one that I want to delete.

On the other hand, the filter method approach apparently works by comparing the **elem**, which is the data passed from a child component, with each element in the **listArray**, and if the element in the for loop does not equal to the **elem**, then it would be passed onto a new array. This new array would be the one to not be deleted. This approach works better than the simple splice approach, however, one problem that I had encountered with this approach is that if I have more than one entry of the same value, for example, "Feed the dog". I only want one of the "Feed the dog" entries to be deleted, but it deletes both of them.

I thought of an approach to tackle this problem, eventually coming up with the current version of my code, which uses the splice method, but the splice method is used before I set it in the state. As evident here:

```
        this.state.listArray.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({
          listArray: this.state.listArray
        });
```

My question can be broken down into three subquestions:

1. Considering that React states should be immutable, is the first line of the code above mutating my state? Is this approach not okay?
2. I thought that all React states were only possible to be changed inside a "setState" function, but my first line of code from above is not inside a setState function, yet it changed the state of **listArray**. How is this possible?
3. If my approach is mutating the state and is not ideal, how would you go about making the delete function so that it only deletes one entry and not more than one if there are multiple similar entries?

Comment: 1. Yes, `splice` [mutates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). So, it is not ok. 2. State *should* be updated with `setState`. But, React is just JS, so you can mutate, change, reassign anything there, even state. This is why they say "only update your state with `setState` and do not mutate it. 3. You can use the item's `index` (see the provided answer), or even better set a unique `id` for every todo and use it to match for the deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `splice` affects the array it acts on so don't use in this way.  Instead you need to create a new array of the correct elements:

```
this.setState({
    listArray: this.state.listArray.filter((el, idx) => idx !== i);
});
```

If you want to remove only the first instance, maybe couple with a `findIndex` (although `indexOf` would work in your example as well) first:

```
delete(elem) {
    const idxToFilter = this.state.listArray.findIndex(el => el === elem);

    if (idxToFilter < 0) {
        return;
    }

    this.setState({
        listArray: this.state.listArray.filter((el, idx) => idx !== idxToFilter);
    });

}
```

This creates a new array without modifying the old which will cause anything that reacts to `listArray` changing to be notified since the reference has changed.

Comment: I tried this approach, but the problem that I encountered was that if there were more than one similar entries in the list, all of those entries would be deleted even if I only want one to be deleted.

Comment: @pdsla112 Then what is `i` in your example?  If you filter with an index that matches `i`, you should only ever filter a single element at a time.

Comment: @pdsla112 See me new edit.  This will only get the first instance of an element.